# Docker build failing when installing polars-lts-cpu

Tags: rust-cargo, python-polars, rust-polars

I'm getting the following error when building my Dockerfile

```
0.894   Downloading polars_lts_cpu-0.18.15.tar.gz (1.9 MB)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
15.39       
15.39       Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
15.39       This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
15.39       the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
15.39       
15.39       Checking for Rust toolchain....
15.39       [end of output]
15.39
```

It's failing on the line `RUN pip3 install polars-lts-cpu==0.18.15`.

I tried to add `RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs -y | sh -s -- -y` to the Dockerfile, but that didn't change anything. It was building fine before, I'm not sure why it's failing now.